# Problem with random generations of objects

Tags: java

Here is my first question(I'm a student, thx for helping before starting): First of all this is a game. I have a matrix as a board, and I want to randomly create objects in random positions of the last column with a frequency "X". For example, the game starts(the board is empty), and player select waiting, the next turn there is a chance of 10% to generate an object. Let's call the object "V".For example, in a 5 x 5 matrix(board) how can I randomly place 3 objects "V" with a 0.1 frequency?

Comment: Think about the various things available to you through random number generation. If you have a random number, let's say from `0-100`, what range of those numbers would occur 10% of the time? (roughly speaking, let's not get into pseudo-randoms). If this is more oriented towards a statistics course and the actual probability distributions matter, a random number generator outside #nextGaussian/etc is probably not what you quite want.

Comment: Start by looking into [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). A common way to have events occur with a certain probability is to check `nextDouble() < X`; `nextInt(bound)` can help you select a random index into your matrix structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, you could use the output of a `Math.random()` call, which returns a random double greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. Simply checking whether it returns a value less than or equal to your frequency (0.1) would do the trick

Example:

```java
boolean randomGenerate = (Math.random() < 0.1);
```

`randomGenerate` shall be assigned `true` only 10% of the time.

As for your second problem, assuming you are using a 2d array as your board, you can randomly generate int array index. As I said earlier, `Math.random()` returns a double, D such that `0.0 ≤ D < 1.0`. Multiplying that by 5 would give you a double D such that `0.0 ≤ D < 5.0`. Casting that double to int would return you an int between 0 and 4. Example:

```java
int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
```

`randomIndex` shall take any value from the set {0,1,2,3,4} with equal probability.

Comment: Yes, that would sove the generation proble, really thank u. But how can i randomly choose a position in the matrix to place it? following the same logic?

Comment: The updated answer would hopefully answer your question